# Randomly assigning equal sized subgroupings within each quantile

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to sort a data frame into quantiles based on a value, and then assign subgroups to each row. These subgroups are supposed to be randomly assigned, but in a way that results in each subgroup having as equal size as possible. So for example, if I have a dataframe of 300 rows, and want 5 quantiles each with 3 subgroups, I would expect 20 rows in quantile 1 subgroup 1, 20 rows in quantile 1 subgroup 2, etc.

Is there a nice and elegant way to do this, that preferably can be piped `%>%` using `dplyr`?

An example of my current code:

```
library(dplyr)

# Construct dataframe.
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
    29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
    45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
    61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
    77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
    93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 
    107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 
    120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 
    133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 
    146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
    159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 
    172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 
    185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 
    198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 
    211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 
    224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 
    237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 
    250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 
    263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 
    276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 
    289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300), 
    value = c(26550.87, 37212.39, 57285.34, 90820.78, 20168.19, 
    89838.97, 94467.53, 66079.78, 62911.4, 6178.63, 20597.46, 
    17655.68, 68702.28, 38410.37, 76984.14, 49769.92, 71761.85, 
    99190.61, 38003.52, 77744.52, 93470.52, 21214.25, 65167.38, 
    12555.51, 26722.07, 38611.41, 1339.03, 38238.8, 86969.08, 
    34034.9, 48208.01, 59956.58, 49354.13, 18621.76, 82737.33, 
    66846.67, 79423.99, 10794.36, 72371.09, 41127.44, 82094.63, 
    64706.02, 78293.28, 55303.63, 52971.96, 78935.62, 2333.12, 
    47723.01, 73231.37, 69273.16, 47761.96, 86120.95, 43809.71, 
    24479.73, 7067.9, 9946.62, 31627.17, 51863.43, 66200.51, 
    40683.02, 91287.59, 29360.34, 45906.57, 33239.47, 65087.05, 
    25801.68, 47854.52, 76631.07, 8424.69, 87532.13, 33907.29, 
    83944.04, 34668.35, 33377.49, 47635.12, 89219.83, 86433.95, 
    38998.95, 77732.07, 96061.8, 43465.95, 71251.47, 39999.44, 
    32535.22, 75708.71, 20269.23, 71112.12, 12169.19, 24548.85, 
    14330.44, 23962.94, 5893.44, 64228.83, 87626.92, 77891.47, 
    79730.88, 45527.45, 41008.41, 81087.02, 60493.33, 65472.39, 
    35319.73, 27026.01, 99268.41, 63349.33, 21320.81, 12937.23, 
    47811.8, 92407.45, 59876.1, 97617.07, 73179.25, 35672.69, 
    43147.37, 14821.16, 1307.76, 71556.61, 10318.42, 44628.43, 
    64010.1, 99183.86, 49559.36, 48434.95, 17344.23, 75482.09, 
    45389.55, 51116.98, 20754.51, 22865.81, 59571.2, 57487.22, 
    7706.44, 3554.06, 64279.55, 92861.52, 59809.24, 56090.07, 
    52602.77, 98509.52, 50764.18, 68278.81, 60154.12, 23886.87, 
    25816.59, 72930.96, 45257.08, 17512.68, 74669.83, 10498.76, 
    86454.49, 61464.5, 55715.95, 32877.73, 45313.14, 50044.1, 
    18086.64, 52963.06, 7527.57, 27775.59, 21269.95, 28479.05, 
    89509.41, 44623.53, 77998.49, 88061.9, 41312.42, 6380.85, 
    33548.75, 72372.59, 33761.53, 63041.41, 84061.46, 85613.17, 
    39135.93, 38049.39, 89544.54, 64431.58, 74107.86, 60530.34, 
    90308.16, 29373.02, 19126.01, 88645.09, 50333.95, 87705.75, 
    18919.36, 75810.31, 72449.89, 94372.48, 54764.66, 71174.39, 
    38890.51, 10087.31, 92730.21, 28323.25, 59057.32, 11036.06, 
    84050.7, 31796.37, 78285.13, 26750.82, 21864.53, 51679.68, 
    26895.06, 18116.83, 51857.61, 56278.29, 12915.69, 25636.76, 
    71793.53, 96140.99, 10014.08, 76322.27, 94796.64, 81863.47, 
    30829.23, 64957.95, 95335.55, 95373.27, 33997.92, 26247.41, 
    16545.39, 32216.81, 51012.52, 92396.85, 51095.97, 25762.13, 
    4646.09, 41785.63, 85400.15, 34723.07, 13144.23, 37448.69, 
    63142.02, 39007.89, 68962.78, 68941.34, 55490.06, 42962.44, 
    45272.01, 30644.33, 57835.39, 91037.03, 14260.41, 41504.76, 
    21092.58, 42875.04, 13269, 46009.64, 94295.71, 76197.39, 
    93290.98, 47067.85, 60358.81, 48498.97, 10880.63, 24772.68, 
    49851.45, 37286.67, 93469.14, 52398.61, 31714.47, 27796.6, 
    78754.05, 70246.25, 16502.76, 6445.75, 75470.56, 62041, 16957.68, 
    6221.41, 10902.93, 38171.64, 16931.09, 29865.25, 19220.95, 
    25717, 18123.18, 47731.37, 77073.7, 2778.71, 52731.08, 88031.91, 
    37306.34, 4795.91, 13862.82, 32149.21, 15483.16, 13222.82, 
    22130.59, 22638.08, 13141.65, 98156.35, 32701.37, 50693.95, 
    68144.25, 9916.91, 11890.26, 5043.97, 92925.39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -300L))
```

Currently I am using this code:

```
groups <- 5
subgroups <- 3

set.seed(30)
result.df <- df %>%
  mutate(group = ntile(x = value, n = groups),
         subgroup = replicate(nrow(df),
                              sample(1:subgroups, 1, replace = T))
         )
```

But when I check the distribution of the subgroups, I find that it is not as equal as it could be.

```
table(result.df$group, result.df$subgroup)

# Returns:
#    1  2  3
# 1 21 22 17
# 2 22 20 18
# 3 24 17 19
# 4 25 15 20
# 5 23 19 18
```

As there are 300 rows, 5 groups, and 3 subgroups, in this case I would like there to be 20 rows assigned to each group. How can this be achieved, in a way that is consistently "random" but also achieves an as equal as possible subgroup size, regardless of the number of quantiles and the number of subgroups?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way :

First shuffle the data set, then create `group` and sort by `group`. Finally create `subgroup` as row number modulo number of `subgroups` :

```
result.df <- sample_frac(df) %>%
  mutate(group = ntile(x = value, n = groups)) %>%
  arrange(group) %>% 
  mutate(subgroup = row_number(group) %% subgroups)

table(result.df$group, result.df$subgroup)
     0  1  2
  1 20 20 20
  2 20 20 20
  3 20 20 20
  4 20 20 20
  5 20 20 20
```

Comment: you can keep in the `dplyr` idiom and shuffle rows with `sample_frac(1)` in the pipe

Comment: Modified. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to systematically assign the random groupings. 
First group by quantiles (as you done), then use the dplyr's `group_by` function to create 5 sets of 60 variables, then assign the each of the subgroups to 20 elements in each parent group.  (Probably does not describe the process well)

```
groups <- 5
subgroups <- 3

result.df <- df %>%
  mutate(group = ntile(x = value, n = groups)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(subgroup = sample(rep(1:3, ceiling(n()/subgroups)), n(), replace = F))

table(result.df$group, result.df$subgroup)

    1  2  3
  1 20 20 20
  2 20 20 20
  3 20 20 20
  4 20 20 20
  5 20 20 20
```

Comment: If the number of rows becomes 301, this code fails due to differences in group size

Comment: See edit for a more general approach.  The second mutate statement can now handle variable sized groups, and prevents the error you encountered.